# Is it a good practice to token gate smart contracts for a user base?

Tags: nft, erc-721, permissions

I want to create a contract like below which restricts access to some functions based on holding of ERC721 token.

```
contract GreetingContract {
    IERC721 public token;
    string greeting;

    function constuctor(string _greeting, address _token) public {
        token = IERC721(_token);
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() public constant returns (string) {
        return greeting;
    }

    function setGreeting(string _newgreeting) public {
        require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= 0, "User does not meet token holding requirements");
        greeting = _newgreeting;
    }
}
```

I want to also use the same ERC721 token to restrict access to functions from some other contracts as well.

Is this a good practice to do so or is there some other implementation pattern which is better ?